# How to do dropdownlist binding in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Home controller action like:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
   List<SelectListItem> oList = new List<SelectListItem>();
   oList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Rest1", Value = "1" });
   oList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Rest2", Value = "2", Selected=true});
   oList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Rest3", Value = "3" });
   Person p = new Person() { PossibleSchools = oList };
   return View(p);
 }
```

Another which gets called on submit button click is ::

```
    public void ModelBinding(Person p)
    {
        var name = p.Name;
    }
```

In view I have following code ::

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<form action="Home/ModelBinding" method="post">
    <p>
  Name :: <input type="text" name="Name"/>
  Restaurant :: @Html.DropDownList("PossibleSchools");
        <input type="submit" />
</p>
</form>    
</div>
```

And my model is ::

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PossibleSchools { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that, whenever I try to debug this application I can see Name field is bound but PossibleSchools count is zero.

Hence dropdownlist is not getting bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a refactored version that might help:

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";   
    Person p = new Person();
    return View(p);
}

public void ModelBinding(Person p)
{
    // Perform action to process the request
}
```

Your Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PossibleSchools 
    { 
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Rest1", Value = "1" }),
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Rest2", Value = "2" }),
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Rest3", Value = "3" })
                };
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in your view:

```
@model Person
<div class="content-wrapper">
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<form action="Home/ModelBinding" method="post">
    <p>
  Name :: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
  Restaurant :: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SchoolName, Model.PossibleSchools)
    <input type="submit" />
</p>
</form>    
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the first line of view use below code:

```
@model Person
<div class="content-wrapper">
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<form action="Home/ModelBinding" method="post">
    <p>
  Name :: <input type="text" name="Name"/>
  Restaurant :: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, Model.PossibleSchools)
        <input type="submit" />
</p>
</form>    
</div>
```